# GDI+ MeasureString() is incorrectly trimming text

Tags: c#, gdi+, measurestring

I am trying to complete a code that can layout text on the screen. The following C# code placed in the `Paint` event handler of an otherwise empty Windows Form is an example:

```
string[] s = new string[] { "Sample text ", "to test", " this layout ", "algorithm" };
PointF[] pts = new PointF[s.Length];
PointF start = new PointF(10, 10);
StringFormat f = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
float x = start.X;
float y = start.Y;
for (int i = 0; i < pts.Length; i++)
{
    pts[i] = new PointF(x, y);
    SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(s[i], Font, pts[i], f);
    x += sz.Width;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(s[i], Font, Brushes.Black, pts[i]);
}
```

It works correctly except for trimming the whitespace before and after each piece of text in the `s` array. It should display like this:

> Sample text to test this layout algorithm

But instead it appears like this:

> Sample textto testthis layoutalgorithm

I have confirmed that the `f.Trimming` property is set to `None`. I would have guessed that this would add trailing and opening whitespace to the measure of the strings, but it still trims it. Any ideas about how to make the `MeasureString` method include the whitespace? The kerning otherwise is handled perfectly.

Answer (score 15):

```
StringFormat f = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic)
                     { FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces };
```