# Why TextRenderer adds margins while measuring text?

Tags: c#, winforms, textrenderer

Because of lack of Graphics object in certain places in my application, I decided to use TextRenderer class. What is quite surprising though is that it adds a lot of margins to measured text. For example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    using (var g = this.CreateGraphics()) {

        Font font = new Font("Calibri", 20.0f, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText("Ala ma kota", font);

        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), size));
        TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "Ala ma kota", font, new Point(10, 10), Color.Black);
    }
}
```

Gives the following result:

[image: Text with margins]

Why does it do so? Is there a way to force it to get the real text size? (and of course draw it in the same rectangle it returns)

Comment: You can try to add in your code a TextFormatFlags Enumeration, as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sy6awsb(v=vs.110).aspx):

> For example, the default behavior of the [`TextRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx) is to add padding to the bounding rectangle of the drawn text to accommodate overhanging glyphs. If you need to draw a line of text without these extra spaces, use the versions of [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`MeasureText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext(v=vs.110).aspx) that take a [`Size`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`TextFormatFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx) parameter, as shown in the example.

You must also pass the `Graphics` object for correct results, because:

> This overload of `MeasureText(String, Font, Size, TextFormatFlags)` will ignore a [`TextFormatFlags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx) value of [`NoPadding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`LeftAndRightPadding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textformatflags(v=vs.110).aspx). If you are specifying a padding value other than the default, you should use the overload of [`MeasureText(IDeviceContext, String, Font, Size, TextFormatFlags)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sy6awsb(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes a [`IDeviceContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.idevicecontext(v=vs.110).aspx) object.

```
Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(g,
                                     "Ala ma kota",
                                     font,
                                     new Size(int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue),
                                     TextFormatFlags.NoPadding);

TextRenderer.DrawText(g, "Ala ma kota", font,
                      new Point(10, 10),
                      Color.Black,
                      TextFormatFlags.NoPadding);

g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), size));
```

Also have a look at using the `Graphics` methods directly: [GDI+ MeasureString() is incorrectly trimming text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11170823/11683)

Comment: +1, that removes the extra padding. But in the place where I do the measuring, I have no `Graphics` object :(

Comment: @Spook Unfortunately this won't work. I have edited in the notes from MSDN. You can however provide your own implementation of `IDeviceContext` that would return e.g. the screen `hDC`, this way you wouldn't need `Graphics`.

Comment: Not good :( It seems I'll have to change architecture of my project, such that Graphics object will be available there...

Comment: @Spook Do you mean creating a graphics object is not allowed, or only that implementing a IDeviceContext would be too much? If the latter, this seems to work: using (var g = FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)){var size = MeasureText(g,s,f,Size.Empty, TextFormatFlags.NoPadding);}                  (Not sure if Intptr.Zero (screen) works on every machine, in the past, I've used a dummy static bitmap and created a Graphics object from that)

Comment: @Me.Name It might have worked, but there's a catch. Since (AFAIR) Windows 8, different windows may have different DPI settings - in such situation I might get invalid metrics if DPIs of window and desktop differs.